# PHP XMLreader to MySQL: put Id value in every insert

Tags: php, mysql, xmlreader

I'm currently working with XMLReader, which I'm using to try and parse certain elements into a MySQL query.

*test.xml*

```
<item>
<id>100</id>
<productdata>
  <g:material>paper</g:material>
  <g:size>25cm</g:size>
  <g:price>69</g:price>
</productdata>
<productdata>
  <g:material>paper</g:material>
  <g:size>35cm</g:size>
  <g:price>79</g:price>
</productdata>
</item>
<item>
<id>101</id>
<productdata>
  <g:material>paper</g:material>
  <g:size>25cm</g:size>
  <g:price>69</g:price>
</productdata>
<productdata>
  <g:material>paper</g:material>
  <g:size>35cm</g:size>
  <g:price>79</g:price>
</productdata>
</item>
```

I want to have the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (‘100’,’paper’,’25cm’,’69’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (‘100’,’paper’,’35cm’,’79’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (‘101’,’paper’,’25cm’,’89’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (‘101’,’paper’,’35cm’,’99’)
```

As it turns out now, it’s like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (‘100’,’paper’,’25cm’,’69’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (’69’,’paper’,’35cm’,’79’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (’79’,’paper’,’25cm’,’89’)
INSERT INTO table (id,material,size,price) VALUES (’89’,’paper’,’35cm’,’99’)
```

Is it possible to pass the id value to every single insert while looping through the XML?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$xmlurl = "test.xml";
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open($xmlurl);

$keys = array();
$values = array();
$valuesId = array();

while ($xml->read()) { 
    switch ($xml->nodeType) { 
        case (XMLREADER::ELEMENT):
            if ($xml->localName == "id") {
                $key = trim($xml->localName);
                $xml->read(); 
                $id = trim($xml->value);
                 $value = trim($xml->value); 


                array_push($keys,"`$key`");
                array_push($values,"'$value'");
                break; 
            }
            if ($xml->localName == "material") {
                $key = trim($xml->localName);
                $xml->read(); 
                $value = trim($xml->value); 

                array_push($keys,"`$key`");
                array_push($values,"'$value'");

                break; 
            }
            if ($xml->localName == "size") {
                $key = trim($xml->localName);
                $xml->read(); 
                $value = trim($xml->value); 

                array_push($keys,"`$key`");
                array_push($values,"'$value'");

                break; 
            }
            if ($xml->localName == "price") {
                $key = trim($xml->localName);
                $xml->read(); 
                if($xml->value != 0) $value = trim($xml->value); 

                array_push($keys,"`$key`");
                array_push($values,"'$value'");

                break; 
            }
    }
    $valuepack = array_chunk($values, 4);   

}
$keys = array_unique($keys); 
$table = "tablename";

foreach($valuepack as $ValAllId => $tablevalueall) {            
    $SQL = "";
    $SQL .= "INSERT INTO $table (";
    $SQL .= implode(", ",$keys);
    $SQL .= ") VALUES (";
    $SQL .= implode(", ",$tablevalueall);
    $SQL .= ");<br />";
    echo $SQL;
}
?>
```

Thanks!

J

Comment: you mean, you want to put the id as an auto increment value and not use the value coming from xml?

Comment: No, I didn't intend to have an auto increment value, but just the id that's mentioned where the item begins. I want that value to be repeated for every productdata block within the item.